# FaceBook JavaScript API in native app UIWebview

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I am creating an app which is reusing some of the HTML pages from my site. In one of the pages, there is a share event in facebook functionality. This is not working in UIWebview as there is no concept of "pop ups" in uiwebview. FB.Login() opens a new tab in an actual browser, but in UIWebview, it loads on top of the existing page.Hence after login, while the actual browser tab closes itself and transfers the control to the callback function in the original tab, UIWebview page just turns blank as it probably cannot find the original call back function anymore. Any solutions?